# Remove a child without an ID in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

My question is, how can i use .removechild() in javascript without having the elements ID?

The reason I don''t have its ID, is because the td was only added using append child, which as far as i know, does not allow adding an ID as well, but i may be wrong?

I used :

```
var myRow = document.createElement("tr");
```

to make the child in my function at the start.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an `id` property to elements you create with `document.createElement()`:

```
var myCol = document.createElement('td');
myCol.id = 'my-col-id';
myRow.appendChild(myCol);
```

Then you can use `document.getElementById('my-col-id')` without problems.

Comment: You also retain the pointer to the element from the declaration. Even after it is inserted the variable myRow (from your example) should still be a valid pointer to that object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can assign ID from code. Try like this:

```
myRow.id = 'the_id';
```

Comment: ahh ok, sorry for asking silly question, couldn't find that anywhere

Comment: @mick: Don't worry. The question is not silly. You may want to mark an answer as accepted by clicking on the green tick, if it was helpful to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
myRow.id = 'someId'
```